# Remove negative numbers and sort an array

Tags: c, sorting

Good day everyone,

my task is to remove all negative numbers from an array, and shorten it (return the new length as the amount of positive numbers). I tried doing that by BubbleSort all negative number to the right, and new length would be (old length - number of swap). My code simply freezes up the system.

I would be grateful if you guys could help.

```
void swap(int *p, int *q) {
    int h = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = h;
}

int remove_negatives(int *array, int length) {
    int *a;
    int n = length;
    a = &array[n - 1];  
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        while (array < a) {
            if (*array < 0) {
                swap(a, array);
                a--;
                array++;
                length--;
            }
        }
    }
    printialn(array, n);
    return length;
};

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {-1, 2, 4, -8, 3, 7, -8, 9, 3};
    int l = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    printiln(remove_negatives(a, l));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is incomplete. What are `printialn` and `printiln`?

Answer (score -1):

The while loop never stops, that's probably the reason your code freezes.
Your code only changes the address when the if statement is true. Which the array in your main() will stuck on the second (a[1]) element. So if we change change the address when the if statement is false...

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void swap(int *p, int *q) {
    int h = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = h;
}

int remove_negatives(int *array, int length) {
    int *a, *head;
    int n = length;
    head = array;
    a = &array[n - 1];  
    for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        while (array < a) {
            if (*array >= 0) {
                array++;
                continue;
            }
            swap(a, array);
            a--;
            array++;
            length--;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", *head);
        head++;
    }
    puts("");
    return length;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {-1, 2, 4, -8, 3, 7, -8, 9, 3};
    int l = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    remove_negatives(a, l);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the while loop works, buts as @wovano said, the answer is still wrong. Your code isn't exactly a "bubble sort". you swap all the negative number to the end of the array and didn't actually sort the array.

So, let's start from the beginning.

To simplify the process, let bubble sort first, and then find the new array length.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void swap(int *p, int *q) {
    int h = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = h;
}

int bubble_sort(int *array, int length) {
    int i, j;

    // Bubble sort
    for (i=0; i<length-1; i++) {
        for (j=i+1; j<length; j++) {
            if (array[i]<array[j]) swap(&array[i], &array[j]);
        }
    }

    // Find new array length
    for (i=length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        if (array[i]>=0) break;
        length--;
    }
    return length;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {-1, 2, 4, -8, 3, 7, -8, 9, 3};
    int l = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
    l = bubble_sort(a, l);
    for (int i=0; i<l; i++) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @wovano I thought he only wants to know why the program freezes, So I only change that part of the code. I edited a new one that prints the correct answer he wants.

Comment: By the way, I don't think the OP wanted to fully sort the array. I think the intention was just to move all negative numbers to one end of the array, so all positive numbers were at the other end. This would take O(n), while bubble sort takes O(n^2) time. Not sure if it's relevant for the question though, because we don't know how long the array is and if time is an important factor. Also, it's possible that sorting the data is not even allowed: the task is _to remove all negative numbers from an array_.

Comment: I tried to edit his question, but he didn't provide enough information, and I don't think he is still online reading all of these. But I still want to answer, so he can get the help he need when he's back. I'm new to SO, too. I think answering questions no one else want to answer that happens to match my skill level is a great way to practice.

Comment: That's not the purpose of Stack Overflow. It's not a personal support or training site. The purpose is _to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming_ (see the [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour)). Questions that are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem shouldn't be answered (see [how to answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)). It's fine that you get inspiration from these questions, but I don't think you should post your code as an answer here. These type of questions and answers don't make the site better.